# Does Dynamic SOQL Support Bind Expressions?

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

I want to show a table of items, when a user clicks on the header of the column, it will sort the items by ASC/DESC.

Based on my internet searches, I need to use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to include variables after the ORDER BY clause. But, I can't seem to find good example where dynamic SOQL was used in the standardsetcontroller.

```
// the current sort direction. defaults to asc
public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
}

// the current field to sort by. defaults to event date
public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Event_Date__c'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
}    
String orderByClause = 'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir;
String eventDateClause = 'AND Event_Date__c >= TODAY';

SSC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.query(
        'select Id, name, Event_Date__c, Event_Description_Short__c, 
         Event_GO_Region__c, Event_Image_URL__c, Event_Publish_Date__c,
         Event_Time__c, Event_Time_Start__c, Event_Time_End__c, Event_Status__c,
         Event_Type__c, Public_Page_URL__c, Event_Coordinator__c,
         Event_Location__c from GO_Event__c 
         WHERE RecordType.Name = \'Corporate Wellness\'
         AND Event_Status__c = \'Display\'
         eventDateClause
         orderByClause'));
```

I'm not getting any errors in the developer console. But I am getting this on my VF page.

[image]

Comment: check js [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, dynamic `SOQL` does not support expression evaluation, so you can't use `Date.today()` inside your string. You can include local variables, but not reference their properties or methods. There is [an Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kkJsAAI) out there to allow properties, but I doubt dynamic soql will ever support expression evaluation.

**[Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)** may be a better choice here, since you can already use:

```
String eventDateClause = 'Event_Date__c >= TODAY';
```

I don't believe the `ORDER BY` clause supports dynamic binding either. That clause would have to merge the variables into the string directly:

```
String orderByClause = 'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir;
```

Comment: to clarify, if I make all my AND's and ORDER BY strings, it should work?

Comment: I think the only things you need to change are the one `Date.today()` filter and the `ORDER BY` clause. You can do dynamic bindings, just not when you have any properties (`:myVariable.someProperty`) or expressions (`:myVariable.someMethod()`) . And `ORDER BY` in particular doesn't support them (not all clauses do).

Comment: If I include the eventDateClause at the end of my string it 'returns unexpected token: '<EOF>' '

Comment: Hard to say what you're doing without seeing it, but you can just modify your initial string. You don't have to introduce a new one, if that's the issue. I can compile this snippet without issue: `Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY')`

Comment: I updated my post with an implementation of your solution. I think I did it correct.

Comment: You should be getting a compile error, `line breaks not allowed in string literals`. But it would be `'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...' + ' AND ' + eventDateClause + ' ' + orderByClause`.